# HTML5 Boilerplate, git prime/hub deployment and ant build for performance - what's the workflow?

Tags: git, ant, build-automation, html5boilerplate

I've been working on a new responsive design and have been using git in a prime/hub setup (see [A web-focused Git workflow](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)).

I'm getting to the point in my project where I want to start using the optimizations in html5bp's ant build script. But I'm unclear on the workflow when one is using git.

Do I code on whichever machine I'm using at the time, run `ant build` locally, then commit the files and push to my server? Do I code, commit, push and then have the post-update script run the optimizations remotely on the server?

Just confused as to what the workflow should be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: commit changes and then run a build on the server.

Obviously the details are more complicated than that, and would depend on your environment,  but it's just much nicer/cleaner to keep the build (and associated artifacts) outside of your source control. The one thing you do need to maintain is the ability to test, locally and on a staged environment the output of minification/concatenation/build script magic.

Comment: Thanks. I'll delve into that a bit further then.